# Adding keyboard shortcuts in my homemade shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

So I have to write a basic shell in C for school, no pipes, no redirections, I just have to execute the binarys and code a few builtins.

I already did most of that, but now I would like to implement some keyboard shortcuts, like ctrl+L to clear the screen, up/down to navigate through commands history, ctrl+D to exit the shell and so on.

The problem is, I have no idea how to read input without the user pressing enter.

Also I should mention that I can only use a very limited panel of functions, the only function I can use to read input is the system call read().

If anyone has an idea it would be great

Answer (score 2):

Generally use the `readline` library to read input. It supports defining shortcuts, history, auto completion, ... and is meant for that purpose.

If you are not allowed to use it, I guess your teacher wants you to concentrate on important parts of the task rather than getting *fancy*.

If you just want to play around a bit, you may start your shell using the [`rlwrap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) command:

```
rlwrap your_shell
```

`rlwrap` can be used to add readline functionality to arbitrary commands which read from stdin.

Comment: I am not allowed to use anything like that

Comment: Yes I realized that now.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this

Comment: This answer has been downvoted. Can the downvoter please give a reason?